# htaccess repeated rename for php file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file called directory.php user is able to arrange content inside by fixing the url `directory.php?letter=a&page=2&orderby=name&donotshowthis=this`... you get the idea.
I am trying to make one line of htaccess to rename all that mess to something that is easier to read what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
directory/letter:a|page:2|orderby:name|donotshowthis:this
```

here is my try on the code: it only works for one string how can I seperate it with | and have unlimited number of strings?

```
RewriteRule ^directory/([a-z]+):(.*)/?$ directory.php?$1=$2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^(directory)(?:\.php)?/([^:]+):(.*?)(?:\x7c(.*))?$" $1.php/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will route your input URI

```
example.com/directory/letter:a|page:2|orderby:name|donotshowthis:this
```

to:

```
example.com/directory.php?donotshowthis=this&orderby=name&page=2&letter=a
```

Comment: Sorry and thank you, it works, it was a test problem. +1

Comment: I wanted to add that if you have php-fpm on, this code does not work for some reason!!! let me know if someone know why and what the possible solution is.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about `php-fpm`. You may want to post a new question using `php` tag so that you can get better help.

Comment: One thing you can try is placement of `Options -MultiViews` line before `RewriteEngine` line